# Rank of a psd matrix and principal minors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, semidefinite-programming

Let $M\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix and assume that $M$ is positive semidefinite. Let $M_i$ be the leading principal ${i\times i}$ minor and assume that $det (M_i)\neq 0$. Now if rank $det (M_{i+1})=0$ thus this sufficie to deduce that rank $M=i$?

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and the case $i = 1$. The leading principal $1 \times 1$ minor has $\det M_1 = 1$ and $\det M_2 = 0$ but $\text{rank } M = 2 \neq 1$.

The conditions stated do guarantee, however, that $\det M_{i + 1} = i$.

Comment: Thanx I was thinking that [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76001/determining-the-rank-of-a-matrix-based-on-its-minors?rq=1) would help, but infact of course it just cofused principla minors with minors in general.

Comment: You're welcome. In general we shouldn't expect anything like this to be true, because it asks about the rank of a linear transformation from a space to itself but only uses information about how that transformation works on a particular subspace.

Comment: Yes, I see. But isn't Theorem 5.20 [here](http://books.google.ro/books?id=5_sxtcnvLhoC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=principal+submatrix+symmetric+matrix&source=bl&ots=ZofYuMgDEF&sig=voqe1jsXU_haJC7_musbYWEizCQ&hl=ro&ei=sUrES9--N8Oj_AbN24SsDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CDYQ6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q=principal%20submatrix%20symmetric%20matrix&f=true) contradicting this general remark you made, too?

Comment: No, because "every principle submatrix" still uses the remaining entries of a matrix. To be clear, we can use partial information to get partial information, for example, if $M$ has an $i \times i$ minor with nonzero determinant, then $\text{rank } M \geq i$. But we can't say that a square matrix has full rank if we don't know anything about one of its columns; it may be in the span of the remaining columns, or it may not be.