# Rouché-Capelli theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I understand what the theorem is about:
[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem ][1]

i.e., the rank of the augmented matrix wrt the rank of the coeff matrix provides information about the solutions to a system of linear equations.

However, since (up to my best knowledge) Gaussian elimination is used to find both the rank of a matrix and the solutions of a linear system, ... then what is the point of this theorem given that we may as well directly find the solutions with Gaussian elimination instead of computing the rank? ...Or is there another way to compute the rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everything is computation of solutions.  In general, it is useful to know the structure of the set of solutions.  Sometimes one wants to find a system that has certain properties.

Comment: ah ok. But still you need to use Gaussian elimination in any case to find the rank, yes?

Comment: @Machupicchu Gaussian elimination is not the only way to get the rank. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006042/minors-and-rank-of-a-matrix